# Alert user when item selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to alert the user when they have selected the value `Mustard` from the dropdown? I have tried to write 'hello' to my console when it happens but no success.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/exq19fdj/

**Code:**

```js
$('select').selectpicker();

$("select").change(function(e) {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    console.log('hello!');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option value="Mustard">Mustard</option>
  <option value="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="Relish">Relish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$(this).val() == "Mustard"`

```js
$('select').selectpicker();

$("select").change(function(e) {
  if ($(this).val() == "Mustard") {
    console.log('hello!');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option value="Mustard">Mustard</option>
  <option value="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="Relish">Relish</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it only writes hello if mustard is the only option chosen, so if it is chosen with ketchup there is no alert, is that how you want it @Mamun?

Comment: This works only when "Mustard" alone selects or deselects.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('select').selectpicker();

$("select").change(function(e) {
 if( $(this).find("option:selected").text().indexOf("Mustard")!=-1){
 console.log("helo");
 }

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option value="Mustard">Mustard</option>
  <option value="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="Relish">Relish</option>
</select>
```

Try this. You can simply check "Mustard" is exists in the selected items by using `indexOf` function. It will return `-1` when no matches found.

Answer (score 1):

For multiselect if you need to check if `Mustard` selected - you need to search through array of selected values. (since multiple values can be selected)

```
$("select").change(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().indexOf('Mustard') !== -1)
        alert('MUSTARD!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").change(function(e) {
   if($(this).selectpicker('val').includes('Mustard')){
       alert('Mustard selected');
   }
});
```

You can use selectpicker method to retrieve selected values.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an event exposed by bootstrap select, `changed.bs.select`.

Also, either use class(`class="selectpicker"`) or javascript(`$('select').selectpicker();`) to initialize the select.

see fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/8o0pcb6r/

```js
$('select').on('changed.bs.select', function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue, x) {
  if ($(this).val() == "Mustard") {
    console.log('hello!');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
  <option value="Mustard">Mustard</option>
  <option value="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="Relish">Relish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I give two solution for single and multi select dropdown event to check if "Mustard" selected or not.

```js
    $('select').selectpicker();
    $("select").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).val().indexOf("Mustard") == 0) {
            alert('hello!');
        }
        //or
        if ($(this).val().toString() == "Mustard") {
            alert('hello!');
        }
        else if ($(this).val() != "") {
            var multiSelect = $(this).val().toString().split(',');
            for (var i = 0; i < multiSelect.length; i++) {
                if (multiSelect[i] == "Mustard") {
                    alert('hello!');
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option value="Mustard">Mustard</option>
    <option value="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
    <option value="Relish">Relish</option>
</select>
```